# IIS URL Rewrite removing part of path

Tags: url-rewrite-module, iis-10

because a Software provider changed the URL of a Programm hosted in my IIS, I now have many broken links.
The URL used to be

```
https://example.com/#/subdomain/and/here/some_more
```

now it is

```
 https://example.com/#/and/here/some_more
```

They just took away the first part of the path (*subdomain*)

I thought I could fix my links with an URL Rewrite rule.
I tried this:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>                
            <rule name="example" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(https:\/\/example\.com\/#)(\/subdomain)(\/.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://example.com/#{R:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This actually matches in the "Test Pattern" but it doesn't redirect. 
[image]

I also tried using :

```
url="{R:1}{R:3}
```

but still no redirect is happening. I tried with different browsers with no success.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number sign (#) delimits the URI from the fragment identifier. The client should never send this character uncoded. Instead, the client should only send the URI to the server (everything before #). So your client application (web browser) does not send anything after #, which we can see in the URL logged on the server. So what you need to do is to encode this character.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Comment: Well the # is used in many SPA as a routing mechanism, also in my provider's single page application site. So you're telling me there is no way to do that with url rewriter?

Comment: you could try to use encoding to change the #. please run the failed request tracing and check that you are getting the other value after the # or not. you can also check iis logs for that.